# .htaccess not working on my phpMyAdmin folder

Tags: centos, .htaccess

I have a phpMyAdmin folder. So first I set .htaccess folder and type this in it.

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-3.4/.htpasswd
AuthName "phpMyAdmin Login Page"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

The I created the username and password using this command

```
sudo htpasswd -c .htpasswd iamadmin
```

...and I could see both the .htaccess and .htpasswd files are in the folder. But when I go my link it never prompt for the additional username and password. My OS is centos 6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will most likely need to configure your server to allow `AuthConfig` directives in `.htpasswd` files. Add an

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

in a suitable place in your httpd configuration (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) file and restart apache

```
service httpd restart
```

See also the apache [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html)

Comment: @lain I have done this # # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that # directory (and its subdirectories). # # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of # features. # <Directory /> Options FollowSymLinks AllowOverride AuthConfig </Directory> Then I restary my httpd still the same. Still no difference anything I am missing is it?

Comment: I would check to see if there are other AllowOverride directives that are restricting access to other directories that may be causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the Wamp Server icon (phpmyadmin)
2. Select Apache
3. Select Apache Modules
4. Select rewrite_module
5. Restart Your Wamp Server
6. Run your program.

If this not working there is problem with your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Your answer has some room for improvement.  There's nothing in the .htaccess file provided that relies on mod_rewrite. Why do you think switching that on will help? Why do you think he's using WAMP? CentOS and WAMP are not commonly found together. "there is problem with your .htaccess file" is not helpful. He came here to ask *what* was wrong with the .htaccess file. Maybe you could focus on [unanswered questions](http://serverfault.com/questions?sort=unanswered) where you have specific expertise.